# why date picker showing only 20 year in option using Jquery date picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using date picker of jquery .As i use default it show year 2003 to 2023 only 20 values .
I need to increase this value .
when i use this code

```
 $(  "#inputBirthDate" ).datepicker({
                                     changeMonth: true,
                                     changeYear: true,

});
```

it show 20 values ..
BUt when I used this it is not showing, it show 2030 to 2050

```
  $(  "#inputBirthDate" ).datepicker({
                                     changeMonth: true,
                                     changeYear: true,
                                     minDate: new Date(1990-01-01),
                                     maxDate: new Date(2050-01-01),
                                     inline: true
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the year range using this option per documentation here http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange

```
yearRange: '1950:2013', // specifying a hard coded year range
```

or this way

```
yearRange: "-100:+0", // last hundred years
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually your first piece of code is working correct.  This is the default behavior of datepicker, check this [demo and code](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year).

```
min: current year -10 (2013 - 10 = 2003)
max: current year +10 (2013 + 10 = 2023)
```

However this can be cahanged using the following option.

```
 yearRange: "-20:+0"
```